Prove that $\frac{(np+1)!}{p\cdot2p\cdot3p\cdot\ldots\cdot np} \equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ p)$.
If $n$ is an even integer and $p$ is a prime, prove that
\begin{equation}
\frac{(np+1)!}{p\cdot2p\cdot3p\cdot\ldots\cdot np} \equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ p)
\end{equation}
I do not know if my solution is correct or not.
My solution is that:
By Wilson's theorem,
\begin{equation} 
\begin{aligned}
(p-1)! &\equiv -1\ (\text{mod}\ p)\\
(np+1)(np)(np-1)\ldots(p+1)(p)(p-1)! &\equiv -(np+1)(np)(np-1)\ldots(p+1)(p)\ (\text{mod}\ p) \\
&\equiv 0\ (\text{mod}\ p) \\
&\equiv p(2p)(3p)\ldots(np)\ (\text{mod}\ p) \\
\frac{(np+1)!}{p\cdot2p\cdot3p\cdot\ldots\cdot np} &\equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ p)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Welcome to MSE. What have you tried so far? On this site, you're supposed to show efforts in order to receive help.

Use Wilson's theorem.

Hi, I just added what I have tried so far, but it is a little bit weird after multiplying both side.

The last step does not work as the term $p\cdot 2p\cdots np$ is not invertible in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Any suggestion on that??

I just posted an answer below.

Note that the fraction can be rewritten as $$(p-1)![(p+1)\cdots(2p-1)]\cdots[(np-p+1)\cdots(np-1)](np+1).$$ Now one uses the Wilson's theorem to deduce that the above expression $\pmod p$ is equal to $$(-1)[(p-1)!]^{n-1}(1)\equiv (-1)^n\equiv 1\pmod p.$$

Notice that for any natural k, we have:
$$ (kp+1)(kp+2)(kp+3) \dots (kp+(p-2))(kp+(p-1)) \equiv (p-1)! \pmod p $$
This is because, after multiplying out, every other term is divisible by p. You should try to express your original expression in terms of this kind of factorization.
Hint: Cancel the common terms in the numerator and denominator.


$\dfrac {(np+1)!}{p\cdot 2p\cdot 3p\cdot \cdots \cdot np} \equiv 1 (\mod p), 2|n.$

\begin{align}
& \dfrac {(np+1)!}{p\cdot 2p\cdot 3p\cdot \cdots \cdot np} = (np+1)\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \prod_{i=1}^{p-1} (kp+i) \\
& \equiv \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \prod_{i=1}^{p-1} i \\
& = \left( (p-1)! \right)^n \equiv (-1)^n =1. \blacksquare
\end{align}
